# Symmetrical difference result in Geotools not drawing correctly

Tags: geotools

I have two polygons and I perform a symmetrical difference on them but the result doesn't make sense. Can anyone explain what could be going wrong? I suppose its something in the geometry, is there a method to verify the geometry before performing the difference?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`isValid()` method](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/Geometry.html#isValid--) on any JTS `Geometry` object to check if it is a valid.

> `public boolean isValid()`
>
> Tests whether this Geometry is topologically valid, according to the OGC SFS specification.
>   For validity rules see the Javadoc for the specific Geometry subclass.
>
> Returns:
>   true if this Geometry is valid
>
> See Also:
>   `IsValidOp`

As a quick check I tried the following:

```
ShapefileDataStore ds = new ShapefileDataStore(URLs.fileToUrl(new File("/home/ian/Data/states/states-nat.shp")));

FeatureCollection features = ds.getFeatureSource().getFeatures(CQL.toFilter("STATE_ABBR = 'PA'"));

SimpleFeature f = (SimpleFeature) DataUtilities.first(features);
MultiPolygon p = (MultiPolygon) f.getDefaultGeometry();

System.out.println(p);

Geometry inner = p.buffer(-10000).getBoundary().buffer(2000);
System.out.println(inner);

Geometry result = p.difference(inner);

System.out.println(result);
```

Which produced:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: if they turn out to be valid, please open a bug report with the WKT of the the two polygons